# How can I change the frequency band ($\tt Fb$ parameter) using $\tt cwtft$?

Tags: matlab, wavelet

MATLAB's implementation of `cwt` uses the complex morlet wavelet as:

```
psi(x) = (pi*Fb)^(-0.5)*exp(2*1j*pi*Fc*x)*exp(-(x^2)/Fb);
```

However, it is possible to implement the `cwt` in the Fourier domain (`cwtft`). In this case, MATLAB uses a slightly different version of the Morlet wavelet:

```
psi = (pi^(1/4)).*exp(2*pi*1j*t)*exp(-(t.^2)/2);
```

The question is: how can I change (or insert) the frequency band parameter in the `cwtft` version?

Would be something like:

`psi2 = (Fb*pi.^(1/4)).*exp(2*pi*Fc*1j*t).*exp(-(t.^2)/(Fb*2));`

if yes, how is the Fourier version of `psi2` (because the implementation takes the fourier transform of `psi2`)?